# How to Spoof Graphics Card for Oculus (Meta, Quest) Software?

Tags: gpu, oculusquest, spoof

I have been searching for a way to trick the Oculus software on my Windows 10 laptop into thinking I have a powerful enough graphics card to sync the Laptop to the Quest3 headset.

The Oculus software wont allow a link between the laptop and the headset because the Oculus software knows that my laptop does not have a GPU.
(I understand why this is).  I just want have my small laptop desktop up and displayed in the headset with a basic program running whilst testing other apps within the Quest3 device.  I am not gaming off the laptop or running any active software...

Thanks,
C